# Initial Value Problem for $y''+xy'+x^2y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anyone have a solution for the initial value problem: $$y''+xy'+x^2y=0, y(0)=1, y'(0)=1 ?$$
I try power series solution but I have trouble finding a pattern for the general term of the series.

Comment: Look at the coefficients! Does $1,x,x^2$ give you a hint?(Euler equation)

Comment: Euler equation is $x^2y''+xy'+y=0$.

Comment: Correct, my bad.

Comment: Please explain what trouble you meet.

Comment: A hint: Writing $y(x):=e^{g(x)}$ and then $g'(x):=h(x)$ produces a first order ODE for $h$ of Ricatti type.

Comment: I get $h'+xh=-h^2-x^2, h(0)=1$. I need a particular solution to solve it. What is a particular solution?

Comment: This might help some: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0205.pdf

Comment: This ODE is really complicated. Even the solution can express in terms of known special functions, they still need their complex order versions: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%22%2Bxy%27%2Bx%5E2y%3D0, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%22%2Bxy%27%2Bx%5E2y%3D0%2Cy%280%29%3D1%2Cy%27%280%29%3D1

Answer (score 1):

The solution of $$h'+xh=-h^2-x^2, h(0)=1$$ seems to be more complex than the solution of $$y''+xy'+x^2y=0, y(0)=1, y'(0)=1$$ as shown by doraemonpaul. I think that the solution you obtained earlier with power series and the nice recurrence relation is probably the best way to go.